# Add delay between values emitted by publisher in Combine Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, delay, combine, publisher

I have one publisher `let subject = PassthroughSubject<Human,Error>()` that emits the following objects,

```
subject.send(Human(fName: "John", lName: "Abraham"))
subject.send(Human(fName: "Jane", lName: "Anne"))
```

I need there to be a delay between these two objects, when they are being received.

```
example(of: "delayy(with:)"){
    
    struct Human {
        let fName: String
        let lName: String
    }

    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Human,Error>()
    let delayInSeconds = 4
    var isLoading = false
    
    subject
        .delay(for: .seconds(delayInSeconds), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        subject.sink(
            receiveCompletion:{
                print("Received Completion", $0)
                isLoading = true
                print("isLoading =", isLoading)
            },
            receiveValue: {

                print("Value Received:" ,$0)
            })

        subject.send(Human(fName: "John", lName: "Abraham"))
        subject.send(Human(fName: "Jane", lName: "Anne"))
        subject.send(completion: .finished)
         
}
```

The First value the publisher is going to be emitting here is `(fName: "John", lName: "Abraham")`. The second value emitted is going to be `(fName: "Jane", lName: "Anne")`.

I want there to be a delay between these two objects when the values are received here in `print("Value Received:" ,$0)`

I tried adding delay but it does not seem to be working. Any help is appreciated. (I am a beginner to combine)

fyi: The above code snippet is from playground

Comment: So the subject must wait *at least* 4 seconds before it publishes the next thing? Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with your code.

---

You do not use the modifier properly.

```
subject
    .delay(for: .seconds(delayInSeconds), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)

subject.sink(
```

Here you assign the `.delay` modifier to your subject. But this will return an new publisher that you simply don´t use. With the next line `subject.sink` you are subscirbing to the original publisher without the delay modifier.

Proper syntax:

```
subject
    .delay(for: .seconds(delayInSeconds), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(
```

---

Next, you are not storing the `AnyCancellable` that is returned by your `.sink` modifier. If you don´t store it, the subscription will go out of scope and you won´t receive new values.

```
let cancellable = subject
                     .delay...
                     .sink...
```

would be the proper way to store it. If you use this in a function or class instead of a Playground take care your `cancellable` var does not go out of scope untill you don´t need it anymore.

---

With these simple issues out of the way lets look at the real problem.

The `.delay` modifier won´t help you here. It just delays the entire stream of emitted values by the delay value given. This means, after sending your values the `delay` function will wait for the specified time and then emit all values at once.

I tried different approaches and the only thing that worked was a combination of a `.buffer` and a `.flatMap` modifier.

```
let cancellable = subject
    .buffer(size: 20000, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .dropOldest)
    .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { Just($0).delay(for: .seconds(delayInSeconds), scheduler: RunLoop.main) }
    .sink(
    receiveCompletion:{
        print("Received Completion", $0, Date())
        isLoading = true
        print("isLoading =", isLoading)
    },
    receiveValue: {
        print("Value Received:" ,$0, Date())
    })
```

The buffer is required to store the values somewhere. The `.flatMap` creates new publishers from the values given but emits only one at a time. This publisher is then delayed by the time you give.

Example input:

```
subject.send(Human(fName: "John", lName: "Abraham"))
subject.send(Human(fName: "Jane", lName: "Anne"))
subject.send(Human(fName: "John2", lName: "Abraham"))
subject.send(Human(fName: "John3", lName: "Abraham"))

subject.send(completion: .finished)
```

Output:

```
Value Received: Human(fName: "John", lName: "Abraham") 2023-02-10 10:58:48 +0000
Value Received: Human(fName: "Jane", lName: "Anne") 2023-02-10 10:58:52 +0000
Value Received: Human(fName: "John2", lName: "Abraham") 2023-02-10 10:58:56 +0000
Value Received: Human(fName: "John3", lName: "Abraham") 2023-02-10 10:59:00 +0000
Received Completion finished 2023-02-10 10:59:00 +0000
isLoading = true
```

This solution has some drawbacks.

- you need to specify the buffer size explicitly in order to avoid losing values
- the completion fires immediately after the last value (don´t know if this is an issue or not)

Comment: You can pass `Int.max` for the size of the buffer.

Comment: This seems to be working for me without the `.buffer(...)` line in a Playground.